# what does the error below mean?

Tags: android

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.landscape);

    // go to the intro activity when button is pressed
    Button introBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.introBtn);
    introBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntroActivity.class));
        }});

    // when back btn is pressed the previous image shows up
    Button backBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previousBtn);
    backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
              backImage();
            ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
            image1.setImageResource(allDrawableImages.get(count));
        }

    });

    // a btn to set wallpaper
    Button setWallBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setWallpaper);
    setWallBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(allRawImages.get(count));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }});

    // go to the next wallpaper image
    Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0){
               nextImage();
            ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
            image2.setImageResource(allDrawableImages.get(count));
            }
        });
        }
```

These are the logs-

```
   03-13 01:14:06.310 7780-7780/com.wube.wubewallpaper
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main


Process: com.wube.wubewallpaper, PID: 7780
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wube.wubewallpaper/com.wube.wubewallpaper.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
at com.wube.wubewallpaper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint somewhere and check that `(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);` is giving you a valid ImageView. It could also be in your loop, `image2.setImageResource(allDrawableImages.get(count))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference"

You're trying to set something that does not exist. If it does exist, double check the placements of all your brackets.  If those are even slightly messed up, it will not work right.